# iterator block to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, iterator, yield-return

I'm having a hard time finding the right LINQ syntax to use for the following iterator block:

```
class Program
{
    class Operation
    {
        public IEnumerable<Operation> NextOperations { get; private set; }
    }
    class Item { }

    static Item GetItem(Operation operation)
    {
        return new Item();
    }

    static IEnumerable<Item> GetItems(IEnumerable<Operation> operations)
    {
        foreach (var operation in operations)
        {
            yield return GetItem(operation);

            foreach (var item in GetItems(operation.NextOperations))  // recursive
                yield return item;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var operations = new List<Operation>();
        foreach (var item in GetItems(operations))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe what I have is as good as it gets?  For this particular code, `yield return` inside an explicit `foreach` is indeed the right solution?

Comment: There are fancier ways of zipping sequences together, but I'm not sure they're an improvement.

Comment: This isn't really zipping in the normal sense.  It's more like a tree traversal.

Comment: @recursive: I think you're correct, but I also think this could be *treated* as an odd, special case of zipping. Not saying it *should*, though.

Comment: Note that this recursive solution is O(nh) in time where h is the height of the tree; since the height of a tree is between lg n and n, this is between O(n lg n) and O(n^2).  This could have very bad performance if the tree is deep. If you write a non-recursive solution with explicit stack management then it becomes O(n) in time and O(h) in space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Maybe what I have is as good as it gets?

It's pretty good. We can make it slightly better.

> For this particular code, yield return inside an explicit foreach is indeed the right solution?

It's a reasonable solution. It's easy to read and clearly correct. The down side is, as I mentioned earlier, that the performance is potentially not good if the tree is extremely deep.

Here's how I would do this:

```
static IEnumerable<T> AllNodes(this T root, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> getChildren) 
{
    var stack = new Stack<T>();
    stack.Push(root);
    while(stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var current = stack.Pop();
        yield return current;
        foreach(var child in getChildren(current).Reverse())
            stack.Push(child);
    }
} 

static void Main()      
{      
    var operation = whatever;
    var items = from op in operation.AllNodes(x=>x.NextOperations)
                select GetItem(op);
    foreach (var item in items)      
    {      
    }      
}
```

Note that the call to Reverse() is necessary only if you care that the iteration go "in order". For example, suppose operation Alpha has child operations Beta, Gamma and Delta, and Delta has children Zeta and Omega. The traversal goes like this:

```
push Alpha
pop Alpha
yield Alpha
push Delta
push Gamma 
push Beta
pop Beta
yield Beta
pop Gamma
yield Gamma
pop Delta
yield Delta
push Omega
push Zeta
pop Zeta
yield Zeta
pop Omega
yield Omega
```

and now the stack is empty so we're done, and we get the items in "preorder traversal" order. If you don't care about the order, if all you need is to make sure you get all of them, then don't bother to Reverse the children, and you'll get them in the order Alpha, Delta, Omega, Zeta, Gamma, Beta.

Make sense?

Comment: Yes, although I suspect the recursive version might be faster than the explicit-stack one, at least for small, flat trees.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your implementation is good. However, if you want to use LINQ (and make it a little bit - but not significantly - shorter), then you can implement `GetItems` using a query that iterates over all operations and returns current item followed by all other recursively generated items:

```
static IEnumerable<Item> GetItems(IEnumerable<Operation> operations) 
{ 
    return from op in operations
           from itm in (new[] { GetItem(op) }).Concat
                       (GetItems(op.NextOperations));
           select itm;
}
```

For each operation, we generate a sequence containing the item for the current one followed by all recursively generated items. By using a nested `from` clause, you can iterate over this collection to get a "flat" structure.

I think you could make it a bit nicer by using a functional (immutable) list which supports operation for "appending an element to the front" - which is exactly what we're doing in the nested `from`. Using [`FuncList` from my functional programming](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/realworldfp) book (this is no longer lazy sequence though):

```
static FuncList<Item> GetItems(IEnumerable<Operation> operations) 
{ 
    return (from op in operations
            from itm in FuncList.Cons(GetItem(op), GetItems(op.NextOperations));
            select itm).AsFuncList();
}
```

As Jon mentioned, there is no good way of writing the recursive aspect using query (you can write recursive query using lambda functions instead of methods - but that's not much better).

Comment: Is there a base case here?  Looks like it will overflow the stack.

Comment: @recursive: I didn't try it, but I think that the base case is when `operations` is an empty sequence - in that case, the query will return empty sequence immediately (the structure of the recursion is the same as in the OP's version).

Comment: @Tomas: ah yes, I see it now.

Comment: @Dan: This is why we have the Kindle. :-)

Answer (score 1):

LINQ isn't generally good at recursion, using the standard query operators. You could write a more general purpose form of the above, but you won't find a neat standard LINQ way of doing this traversal.

Comment: What do you think of Tomas' answer, then?

Comment: @Steven: It's fine, but it still requires the recursive part. You can't just do it all in one statement, with no extra methods and no extra variable to represent the action to use recursively.

Comment: Or, per Lippert's analysis, use an extra variable with an explicit stack in lieu of the recursion. Fun stuff.